# Wordpress is_user_logged_in restriction

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to have a page outside of Wordpress use the is_user_logged_in function to determine if they can view some data or not. I am definitely logged in and the paths to the Wordpress files are correct. Anyone have any thoughts why I can't see the data?

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    include('../blog/wp-load.php');
    include('../blog/wp-blog-header.php');

    if(is_user_logged_in()) {
            //Do Something
    } else {
            echo 'Not logged in';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Is this a hidden page you generated through the WP admin with a custom template? or a PHP page you are trying to hook into WP functions? Also, is this outside of your WP installs URL (site.com/blog and the page you are creating is at site.com/restricted_page.php)?

Comment: Looks like you ended up with the same answer as other people. Looks like a cookies issue unless you are working from the same directory: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/checking-wordpress-login-status-from-outside-the-blog#post-946277

Answer (score 1):

I used require instead of include and your code is perfect now.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
// include('/wp-blog-header.php');

if(is_user_logged_in()) {
        //Do Something
    echo "LoggedIN";
} else {
        echo 'Not logged in';
}
?>
```